# Cant understand why the for loop get out of range

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I am learning c#, and have home works to make simple dictionary in console aplication.
I wrote all the code and it should work good but in one of the for loops the program throws `Error:System.IndexOutofRange`.
I tried all I know (I am only beginner so I dont know much) but it always gives the error.
The main idea of the program is the user must enter how much words he wishes to use then enter the words in the his language (my is Hebrew so in the program is Hebrew) and in English and it save the words in two deffernt Arrays but in same index. Then the program ask the user to enter sentence in his language and then the program runs on the sentence finds the words (each time the program see space it starts a new word), then with another for loop it looks in the Hebrew Array and if it finds match place the word that in the same index but in the English Array, and if not found it writes the original word.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of words you wish to use");
        int wordsNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        string[] hebrew = new string[wordsNumber];
        string[] english = new string[wordsNumber];

        for (int i = 0; i < wordsNumber; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter word in Hebrew.");
            hebrew[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Now enter the translate of {0} in English.",hebrew[i]);
            english[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Now enter the sentence that you want to translate..and press ENTER");
        string searchSentence = Console.ReadLine();
        string translateWord = "";
        string result = "";
        while(searchSentence != "stop")
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < searchSentence.Length;i++ )
            {
                translateWord = "";
                while ((searchSentence[i] == ' ')&&(searchSentence.Length > i))//Skip the spaces      in the start of the sentence
                    i++;
                while ((searchSentence[i] != ' ') && (searchSentence.Length > i))//Here is the problem when with the OutOfRnge
                {
                    translateWord += searchSentence[i];
                    i++;
                }
                for(int j = 0;j<hebrew.Length ;j++)
                {
                    if (translateWord == hebrew[j])
                    {
                        result += english[j];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result += translateWord[i];
                    }
                    result += " ";
                 }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter new sentence for translate or enter 'stop' to EXIT the  programm");
            searchSentence = Console.ReadLine();  
        }
```

Comment: which exact line gives you the error

Comment: Your code seems pretty confusing but it could quite easily go out of range when looking up `searchSentence[i]` if `Length == i`

Comment: I wrote in the code with comment (its line 38)

Comment: you should change the condition with searchSentence.Length > (i-1) if the length for example is 8 the array go from 0 to 7

Comment: I am only begginer so all i know to use and able is Arrays for/while loops and int/double/string/char/bool vars types

Comment: @SalvatoreSorbello in both loops?

Comment: @satis, yes, anyway i didnt read with so much attention, btw this is a good example to start learning to use the breakpoints/step by step execution

Comment: I made debugging many times but still cant fix the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   while ((searchSentence[i] != ' ') && (searchSentence.Length > i))
```

Consider that the way you are used to read (right-to-left in your neck of the woods) is affecting the way you write code.  This code is backwards, both in the order of the && operands and in the Length test.  And thus doesn't take advantage of the *short-circuiting* behavior of the && operator.  Probably difficult to unlearn, something you'll have to work on.

Avoid this exception with:

```
   while ((i < searchSentence.Length) && (searchSentence[i] != ' '))
```

Which ensures that searchSentence[i] cannot throw the IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: but you could get the same expction later on in there code with yhis at this line `result += translateWord[i];`

Comment: I definitely think that it was the expectation of reading right to left that may be the real issue here +1 for that,

Comment: That's backwards too, it is "believe" :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code was very confusing and it would be hard to tell where the error was.. However you would be better off constructing a dictionary full of translations and then using that. I have left out error handling for you to expand upon but here is an example of doing the exact same - but with a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, string> words = new Dictionary<string, string>();

Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of words you wish to use");
int wordsNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i < wordsNumber; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter word in Hebrew.");
    string hebrew = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Now enter the translate of {0} in English.", hebrew);
    string english = Console.ReadLine();

    words.Add(hebrew, english);
}

Console.WriteLine("Now enter the sentence that you want to translate..and press ENTER");
string searchSentence = Console.ReadLine();

string[] splitSentence = searchSentence.Split(new char[]{' '});
string result = "";

foreach (string s in splitSentence)
    result += string.Format("{0} ", words[s]);

Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I sure that this is better solve but i still can't use this methods(Dictionary/Split/Add/Format) i even still dont know what they do.

Comment: @satis - That is for you to research... Dictionary is a type in c# that constructs a sort of table of key (hebrew here) and values (english), which then makes it very easy and quick to find the required value. MSDN is a great website for your research and you can search on google for "MSDN Method/Class/Type name" to quickly find reesults... for example "MSDN Dictionary" returns [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a first result

Answer (score 0):

Looking at

```
 while(searchSentence != "stop")
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < searchSentence.Length;i++ )
        {
            translateWord = "";
            while ((searchSentence[i] == ' ')&&(searchSentence.Length > i))//Skip the spaces      in the start of the sentence
                i++; //updated here and used on nex line when i could be greater than SearchSentence.Length now
            while ((searchSentence[i] != ' ') && (searchSentence.Length > i))//Here is the problem when with the OutOfRnge
            {
                translateWord += searchSentence[i];
                i++; // updated here
            }
            for(int j = 0;j<hebrew.Length ;j++)
            {
                if (translateWord == hebrew[j])
                {
                    result += english[j];
                }
                else
                {
                    result += translateWord[i];
                }
                result += " ";
             }
        }
```

You increment `i` inside the for loop. If it becomes equal to or greater than `searchSentence.Length` then you use it it will throw the error you get

edit to fix make this change from this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < searchSentence.Length;i++ )
        {
            translateWord = "";
            while ((searchSentence[i] == ' ')&&(searchSentence.Length > i))//Skip the spaces      in the start of the sentence
                i++;
            while ((searchSentence[i] != ' ') && (searchSentence.Length > i))//Here is the problem when with the OutOfRnge
            {
                translateWord += searchSentence[i];
                i++;
            }
            for(int j = 0;j<hebrew.Length ;j++)
            {
                if (translateWord == hebrew[j])
                {
                    result += english[j];
                }
                else
                {
                    result += translateWord[i];
                }
                result += " ";
             }
        }
```

to this

```
for (int i = 0; i < searchSentence.Length;i++ )
{
if(((searchSentence[i] != ' ')&&(searchSentence.Length > i)))
{
    while ((searchSentence[i] != ' ') && (searchSentence.Length > i))//Here was the problem when with the OutOfRnge
    {
            translateWord += searchSentence[i];
            i++; // updated here
        if(i>=searchSentence.Length)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i>=searchSentence.Length)
    for(int j = 0;j<hebrew.Length ;j++)
    {
        if (translateWord == hebrew[j])
        {
            result += english[j];
        }
        else
        {
            result += translateWord[i];
        }
        result += " ";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is exactly the answer? I fail to see it.

Comment: They update the incrementor of the for loop inside the for loop then use it to access the array if it is on final tick of the loop then they increase it by 1 it will then throw out of  bounds error

Comment: Yes, I got that part, but how do you solve it? You are not giving a solution, just a reason.

Comment: The question is to understand why they get the error not to fix the error

Comment: It is often better to also provide a solution. An answer without solution feels a bit emtpy to me.

Comment: But here it will not skip the spaces in the begining of the sentence

Comment: @satis: Work out by hand what happens if your sentence ends with a space character. Your code increments i to be outside of the bounds of the array in that case. You can also avoid the start/end of string spaces by using `Trim()` method of `string` type.

Comment: yes it will skip the space look at the if statement